# setState not updating widget saved in variable

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

```
class _OrdersState extends State<Orders> {
  Map<String, List<Order>> queryResults = defaultResponse;

  apiCall(){
    setState(() {
            queryResults = resultFromAPI;
     });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
   Widget homePage = OrdersHome(
      futureOrders: queryResults["futureOrders"] ?? [],
      newOrders: queryResults["newOrders"] ?? [],
      processingOrders: queryResults["processingOrders"] ?? [],
      readyOrders: queryResults["readyOrders"] ?? [],
    );

    print(queryResults["futureOrders"]);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Header(navigatorKey: navigatorKey),
      ),
      body: Navigator(
        key: navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: curRoute,
        onGenerateInitialRoutes: (navigator, name) {
          return [
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return homePage;
            })
          ];
        },
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
         

          if (routeName?.startsWith(RouteNames.ORDERS_PREFIX) ?? false) {
            Widget page = homePage;
            switch (routeName) {
              case RouteNames.ORDERS_HOME:
                page = homePage;
                break;
             // other routes
            }

            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return page;
            });
          } else {
            print('route not found');
           return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return homePage;
            });
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am using OrdersHome() at multiple places so to avoid code duplication I declared it as variable and used variable in UI. But when the state is updated the variables passed in it are not updated.print statement shows that state is updated and build is called again. If I don't use the variable and duplicate that code everywhere it works. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: you are using setState thats why it is not changing. when you will change the screen it will loose it's state and will get back to default value. So for that you have to use one of Provider, mobX, bloc, riverpod etc like state management technique to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the initial value in an InitState. Try this:

```
class _OrdersState extends State<Orders> {
  
late Map<String, List<Order>> queryResults;

  @override
  void initState() {
    queryResults = defaultResponse;
    super.initState();
  }

  apiCall(){
    setState(() {
            queryResults = resultFromAPI;
     });
  }
```